# Creating and selecting configuration definitions in Visual Studio 2017 Mac

Tags: visual-studio

This is a very simple build configuration task that I have so far been unable to get Visual Studio 2017 for Mac to work properly.

Normally there is the concept of Debug and Release options that can be selected when running a solution. All I want to do is the following

1. Add a new configuration
2. If that configuration is selected then some additional defines are pulled into the project
3. So that I can have something similar to the following

   #if MYIP
   this.ipaddress = MYIP;
   #else
   this.ipaddress = "192.168.1.1";
   #endif

This is very basic configuration management. I have found the Solution Options and added a new config which is based of the existing Debug configuration and I have, eventually, found the Project Options and the Run configurations, where I have set an environment variable called MYIP and set it to a different value.

There appears to be no way of linking this build configuration with the solution configuration. And the Microsoft help is very poor in this area and refers to menu options that do not exist in the Mac version.

So is there a way in Visual Studio to define addition definitions and pull them into the solution? This, to me, seems a core configuration management property and yet doesn't seem to work as expected.

Kind regards, Ian

Comment: I have something that works, not what I was hoping for but I am at least able to achieve the goal I was after.

I've basically gone into the Project Options, gone into the compiler and selected the appropriate configuration (as defined in the solution configuration) and added to the Define Symbols:- CONFIG1 for my first alternative configuration and CONFIG2 for my second.

Then in the solution options, ensure that build -> configurations -> configuration  mappings is pointing to the new configuration. Then in code have

#if CONFIG1
#define MYIP="192.168.3.4"
#elif CONFIG2
...